# If an ordered ring $A$ has an upper bound, does it have to have a lower bound?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I would say yes, because for every $a \in A$ there is $-a \in A$, so if it has a upper bound, it has a finite number of positive elements, therefore it has to have a finite number of negative elements.

I can't rigorously proof this, so I can't actually see if it's true.

Comment: what kind of order are you imposing on the ring?

Comment: Oh, it's an ordered ring. I've edited the question, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha\in A$ is an upper bound, then $\alpha\geq a$ for all $a\in A$. Then for $a\in A$ arbitrary,
\begin{align*}
\alpha&\geq a\\
\implies \alpha + (-\alpha - a)&\geq a + (-\alpha - a)\\
\implies -a&\geq -\alpha.
\end{align*}
Since $a$ was arbitrary, what can you conclude?

Comment: It also has a lower bound, $-\alpha$. Thank you!

Comment: @dumb_undergrad I don't think you appreciate the hint given. It proves *that the ring only has one element* since $\alpha=a$.

Comment: Doesn't that just mean that the upper bound $\alpha$ is bigger than any element and $ - \alpha$ is smaller than any element? I fail to see how it proves that it ony has one element. Also, what if the upper bound isn't in the ring? (Like in a subset of the reals you can have a upper bound not in the subset - I know this isn't a ring, but it's to convey the idea)