# If ordered ring $A$ has upper or lower bound, then, $A = \{0\}$ (alternative proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ordered-groups

Knowing that any ordered ring $A \neq \{0\}$ is infinite, can I say that if an ordered ring is finite, it must be $\{0\}$ ?

By this result - [If an ordered ring $A$ has an upper bound, does it have to have a lower bound?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312786/if-an-ordered-ring-a-has-an-upper-bound-does-it-have-to-have-a-lower-bound) - a ring with an upper bound or a lower bound is finite.

Then, to show that if ordered ring $A$ has upper or lower bound, then $A = \{0\}$, I just have to say that:

Upper or lower bound implies upper AND lower bound which means ring is finite.
Ring is finite, so, by my first paragraph, it must be {0}

Is this right?

Comment: Isn't your first line just stating the contrapositive?

Comment: A remark: it's not clear how you're coming to the conclusion that the existence of an upper or lower bound (or even both) implies that the ring is finite. How are you discounting the possibility that there are infinitely many $\alpha$ such that $\ell < \alpha < u$, where $u$ is the upper bound and $\ell$ is the lower bound? (Think about how a closed interval $[a,b]$ in the real numbers has an upper bound and a lower bound but still has infinitely many elements.)

Comment: Zachary Selk, I don't think so, because having upper and lower bound doesn't imply that is finite - that should come from my second line.

But according to Stahl, existence of upper and lower bound doens't imply that the ring is finite, so I don't think the proof holds.

Comment: The solution [at your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2312810/29335) already proves that if $\alpha$ is an upper bound, $\alpha=a$ for every $a\in A$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that the ordered ring $A$ has an upper bound (an element greater or equal than any other element in $A$) and that $A$ is not trivial.

Then there exist $a\in A$ such that $a\neq 0$. If $a>0$, then $0$ is not the upper bound. If $a<0$, then $-a>0$ so by the same reasoning, $0$ is still not the upper bound.

Let $u$ be the upper bound of the ring $A$. We know that $u>0$. This implies that $u+u>u$ because the order relation $>$ has to be compatible with addition. But this contradicts the fact that $u$ is the upper bound because we have found a greater element in the ring $A$.

This proves that the ordered ring has to be trivial if it has an upper bound.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that proof, but I wanted to check if this alternate proof held. Apparently not, according to Stahl, above. Thanks for your input!